# Why PUT method always returns a 500 error code?

Tags: java, http, servlets, error-handling, put

I'm trying to handle exceptions in Java Servlets application.

When client sends PUT method with non-existing id I want to return him a 404 error.

Here is the servlet's **doPut** method:

```
    @Override
    protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        cors(response);
        String requestBody = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        HumanBeingDTO humanBeingDTO = gson.fromJson(requestBody, HumanBeingDTO.class);
        HumanBeing humanBeingToUpdate = humanBeingMapper.mapHumanBeingDTOToHumanBeing(humanBeingDTO);
        entityValidator.validateHumanBeing(humanBeingToUpdate);
        entityValidator.validateCoordinates(humanBeingToUpdate.getCoordinates());
        entityValidator.validateCar(humanBeingToUpdate.getCar());
        String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
        String id = null;
        if (pathInfo != null)
            id = pathInfo.substring(1);

        if (id != null) {
            try {
                long intId = Long.parseLong(id);
                repository.findById((int) intId);
                humanBeingToUpdate.setId(Long.parseLong(id));
                repository.update(humanBeingToUpdate);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new BadRequestException("Bad format of id: " + id + ", should be natural number (1,2,...)");
            } catch (NoResultException e) {
                throw new NotFoundException("No HumanBeing with id " + id);

            }
        }
    }
```

This is exception handler's class:

```
@WebServlet(name = "NotFoundExceptionHandler", value = "/notFoundExceptionHandler")
public class NotFoundExceptionHandler extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setStatus(404);
        Throwable error = (Throwable) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        resp.getWriter().println(error.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It catches the exception:

```
exceptions.NotFoundException: No HumanBeing with id 80
    at servlets.HumanBeingServlet.doPut(HumanBeingServlet.java:117)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
```

But server still returns 500 code
[image]

Also weird that GET method with same logic returns 404 code, so the error handling is working, but not with PUT method

doGet method:

```
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        cors(response);
        String perPage = UrlParametersUtil.getField(request, "pageSize");
        String curPage = UrlParametersUtil.getField(request, "pageNumber");
        String sortBy = UrlParametersUtil.getField(request, "orderBy");
        String filterBy = UrlParametersUtil.getField(request, "filterBy");

        String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
        String id = null;
        if (pathInfo != null)
            id = pathInfo.substring(1);

        if (id != null) {
            String finalId = id;
            try {
                int intId = Integer.parseInt(id);
                if (intId <= 0) throw new BadRequestException("Bad format of id: " + id + ", should be natural number (1,2,...)");
                HumanBeing humanBeing = (repository.findById(intId)).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("humanBeing with id = " + finalId + " does not exist"));
                HumanBeingDTO humanBeingDTO = humanBeingMapper.mapHumanBeingToHumanBeingDTO(humanBeing);
                response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(humanBeingDTO));
                return;
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                throw new BadRequestException("Bad format of id: " + id + ", should be natural number (1,2,...)");
            }catch (NoResultException e){
                throw new NotFoundException("No HumanBeing with id " + id);
            }
        }

        PagedHumanBeingList pagedHumanBeingList = repository.findAll(perPage, curPage, sortBy, filterBy);
        HumanBeingDTOList dto = new HumanBeingDTOList((humanBeingMapper.mapHumanBeingListToHumanBeingDTOList(pagedHumanBeingList.getHumanBeingList())), pagedHumanBeingList.getCount());
        response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(dto));
        repository.clearEntityManager();
    }
```

doGet response:

[image]

Thanks for any help or advice)

Comment: Most probably some additional exception occurs between "resp.setStatus(404);" and the end of the method. Add more logging to it and make sure all the code gets executed until the end.

Comment: I added logging information, and service method in exception handler isn't even invoking with PUT request, weird